# How to dismantle La Scala E61 group shower

Tags: espresso-machine

I have a hard time dismantling the group shower of a La Scala Butterfly. The main problem is, that there is —as I have seen so far on other machines— any visible screw nut on the bottom of the sieve. It is stuck, does not turn, even by force using a pipe wrench.

[image: La Scala E61 groups shower]

Comment: good pictures. How did you manage to turn the sieve? Did you use a tool?

Comment: I used a pipe wrench and soaked it in _asaco_ coffee washer for a day before pulling it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking about this for days, reading every repair or rebuild history I could find in the internet, I realized that there is one more possibility. The sieve is mounted bottom facing and as it is an exposed part, facing a lot of shaking on the most outer edge (and as the La Scala engineers have shown some engineering details that already impressed me), it could be that the thread is milled counter clockwise. <strike>And yes, *it is*.</strike> *Edit, which I forgot: It just stuck due to the massive amount of old coffee. There was no thread at all.*

Dismantled sieve:

[image: La Scala Butterly E61 group shower sieve]

[image: La Scala Butterly E61 group shower]

Comment: And it looks like it is time for a good cleaning!!

Comment: @NateM. Yep, it is. Sadly the sieve is so messed up, the coffee inside it turned into stone. Guess I have to replace it.